# Morphia Query returning Null on second search, not first?

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I'm writing the backend for my app using MongoDb and Morphia, but I've run into an interesting problem with saving embedded objects.

Let's say I'm writing forum software.  There are Posts (parent objects) and Comments (child objects).  Each Post contains an ArrayList of Comments.  I can make a Post, then add one Comment to it.  That works fine.  If I try to add a second Comment, it seems like my Morphia Query is returning a null object when it searches for the Post to attach the Comment to.

Here is the code, which is inside my processComment method:

```
// Get Owner and ParentObjectId from the incoming JSONObject.
String commentOwner = jsonObject.getString("owner");
String parentObjectUuid = jsonObject.getString("parentObjectUuid");

// Create a new Comment from these values, and add the body.
Comment comment = new Comment(commentOwner, parentObjectUuid);
comment.setBody(jsonObject.getString("body"));

// Get Parent Object from Datastore.
Query<Post> query = datastore.createQuery(Post.class);
query.field("uuid").equalIgnoreCase(parentObjectUuid);
Post parentObject = query.get(); // <--- This is Line #144 where I think it fails.

// Add comment to its ParentObject, and save in our datastore.
parentObject.addComment(comment);
datastore.save(parentObject);
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.EmbeddedMapper.fromDBObject(EmbeddedMapper.java:76)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.readMappedField(Mapper.java:850)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.fromDb(Mapper.java:282)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.fromDBObject(Mapper.java:193)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.convertItem(MorphiaIterator.java:134)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.processItem(MorphiaIterator.java:146)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.next(MorphiaIterator.java:117)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.query.QueryImpl.get(QueryImpl.java:236)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.query.QueryImpl.get(QueryImpl.java:227)
    at IncomingProcessor.processComment(IncomingProcessor.java:144)
    at IncomingProcessor.processIncomingJson(IncomingProcessor.java:78)
    at IncomingProcessor.<init>(IncomingProcessor.java:50)
    at Main.main(Main.java:78)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mongodb.morphia.Key.hashCode(Key.java:149)
    at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:338)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:611)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.cache.DefaultEntityCache.notifyExists(DefaultEntityCache.java:82)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.cache.DefaultEntityCache.putEntity(DefaultEntityCache.java:90)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.fromDb(Mapper.java:293)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.EmbeddedMapper.readMapOrCollectionOrEntity(EmbeddedMapper.java:210)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.EmbeddedMapper.readCollection(EmbeddedMapper.java:144)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.EmbeddedMapper.fromDBObject(EmbeddedMapper.java:47)
    ... 12 more
```

Just to be clear, this code works the first time. When I try to add a second comment, it fails.
Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Isn't the NPE at `IncomingProcessor.processIncomingJson(IncomingProcessor.java:78)`? Also `jsonObject.getString("owner")` looks weird to me — Morphia should take care of that automatically. You shouldn't need to manually map member variables.

Answer (score 0):

Morphia was re-saving the entire Object, which changed an internal hashcode that MongoDB uses to identify the Object.  The code that solved the problem is as follows:

```
// This gets the Post parent object from the DB.
Query<Post> query = datastore.createQuery(Post.class).field("uuid").equal(objectUuid);

// This save the newComment to an ArrayList<Comment> called commentsList.
datastore.update(query, datastore.createUpdateOperations(Post.class).push("commentsList", newComment));
```

This drove me crazy.  I was using the datastore.save() method, which was wrong.  I needed to use the datastore.update() method on a CreateUpdateOperations with the .push() method.

There was much cursing to get here.  Not sure I like Morphia.